# error 'propTypes' is not defined and error 'defaultProps' is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, react-proptypes

I am working on some accessibility issues on a `react-redux` application.

I installed `npm install eslint eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@4.0.0 --save-dev` and now when I run my application I get the following errors:

```
Failed to compile.

Error in ./src/components/Promo.jsx

/code/src/components/Promo.jsx
  15:10  error  'propTypes' is not defined       no-undef
  19:10  error  'defaultProps' is not defined    no-undef
  42:3   error  'updateCellCode' is not defined  no-undef

✖ 3 problems (3 errors, 0 warnings)
```

I do not see any syntax errors and the code looks right to me:

```
import React, { PureComponent, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { throttle, prepAndFormatForInnerHTML } from '../util';
import '../assets/styles/application/promo.css';
import Promos from '../assets/strings/promos.json'; // placeholder info

const MOBILE_BREAKPOINT = 679; // from scss file

/** Used in Account, App, and OrderStatus */
class Promo extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    hideOnSmall: PropTypes.bool,
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    hideOnSmall: false,
  }

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.updateCellCode = throttle(this.updateCellCode, 100);

    this.state = {
      cellCode: Promos[0].cellCodeWeb,
    };
  }
```

Can anybody else see what is wrong here? Why am I getting these errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PropTypes` now is a [separate](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes) package (since `React v15.5`).

So instead of

```
import { PropTypes } from 'react';
```

please use

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

What about actual error - you can try to use the `eslint` of version **3** ([see more](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2528#issuecomment-308180146) about this).

Comment: falinsky, should I be getting these errors even if I am using React 15.3? `PropTypes` does not come as its own package until React 16.

Comment: if you're using react 15.3 - you have to import `PropTypes` from react package. they extracted it onto a separate library in react v15.5. what about errors - it seems they are related to eslint version, not the react one. have you tried eslint v3?